# How to use Texture.clone in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

My problem is very basic : I have a texture object, I want to clone it but Texture.clone doesn't seem to work as expected

My code is as basic as my problem :

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 512;
canvas.getContext("2d").fillStyle = "#ff0000";
canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(0,0,512,512);

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 
texture.needsUpdate= true;

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:texture}); 
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100), material); 
scene.add(mesh)

//please, don't focus on "scene" and the webglrenderer object,
//it's define on the top of my code but it's not important here.
```

This code works as expected.

BUT if I change the line containing the material definition by

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:texture.clone() });
```

nothing appear on the screen ! 
Why ?!

EDIT : Thanks to "TheJim01" , I realized that I didn't apply the "needsUpdate = true" on my cloned-texture.

With

```
var cloneTexture = texture.clone();
cloneTexture.needsUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:cloneTexture });
```

Everything works as expected. 
Thank you

Comment: Are you using a render loop (like most of the thrree.js examples), or are you only rendering once? Also, which version of three.js are you using?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're not using [`CanvasTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture)? The base [`Texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture) constructor takes an [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) as its first parameter.

Comment: In my example, I render it just once. 
I tryed with an old version of Three.js and the last version on github

Comment: CanvasTexture is actually a Texture with "this.needsUpdate = true" in the constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't dug into the renderer code, so I don't know how it uses this information, but `Texture.needsUpdate` increments the "version" of the texture. `CanvasTexture` sets this right away, causing the version value to be `1` on the first render.

`Texture.clone` doesn't perpetuate the version information, and instead re-calls its constructor. Because you aren't setting `needsUpdate` after the clone, you are not following the same steps.

```
// from your code:
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 
texture.needsUpdate= true;
// texture.version === 1

// but...

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map:texture.clone() });
//material.map.version === 0
```

So the clone you're passing into the new material has a `version` of `0`, which is apparently no good if you're using a `canvas` as the source.

This should resolve the issue:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map:texture.clone() });
material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: You're right, thank you a lot ! 
I realized that one minute ago, while I was creating a jsfiddle. 
Because I applyed "needsUpdate" on the original texture just before the call of Texture.clone, I thought it should work but it really needs "needsUpdate".
Thanks again for you reactivity and your time !

Comment: `three.module.js:20349 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is undefined` getting this after `clone()` and `needsUpdate= true` =(

Comment: @godblessstrawberry Make sure your texture is fully loaded first. You can check this by simply checking the state of [`Texture.image`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture).